# Node cannot run serverless cmd

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-serverless

I tried updating both Serverless module and Node, but still receives the same error.

I count not even find the solution in the internet for this simple problem.

[image]can someone suggest.

Comment: Try doing what it suggest. Type `set SLS_INTERACTIVE_SETUP_ENABLE=1` and then run serverless

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I was missing the following directory in my Windows PATH env variable:

```
%AppData%\npm
```

Once I added that I could run serverless, SLS, etc.

Don't forget the restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Go and set an environment variable.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to settings
2. Go to systems
3. Go to Advanced systems settings
4. Click `environment variable`
5. Under `user variables` click new
6. Enter `SLS_INTERACTIVE_SETUP_ENABLE` as the variable name.
7. Enter `1` as the variable value.
8. Click `OK` to save the new environment variable.
9. Close the terminal and reopen it.

Now run your command